# Изменение непрозрачности при наведении

Tags: html, css

Добрый вечер! Предо мной стоит задача сделать так чтобы при наведении на один из шрифтовых иконок она становилась полностью непрозрачной, остальные же оставались полупрозрачными как это и работает сейчас при наведении на div.icons, прикрепляю разметку CSS и HTML

В моём случае при наведении на иконку она так и остается полупрозрачной, способы прикрепил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

CSS:

```
.fa-vk {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: #404040;
    transition: 0.35s;
    font-size: 2.375em;
    transition: 0.35s;
    margin-top: 40%;
    margin-left: 30%;
}

.fa-vk:hover {
    color: #249cce;
    transition: 0.35s;
    background: #fff;
}

.fa-facebook {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: #404040;
    font-size: 2.375em;
    transition: 0.35s;
    margin-top: 40%;
    margin-left: 30%;
}

.fa-facebook:hover {
    color: #249cce;
    transition: 0.35s;
}

.fa-twitter {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: #404040;
    font-size: 2.375em;
    transition: 0.35s;
    margin-top: 40%;
    margin-left: 30%;
}

.fa-twitter:hover {
  color: #249cce;
  transition: 0.35s;
}

.fa-github {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: #404040;
    font-size: 2.375em;
    transition: 0.35s;
    margin-top: 40%;
    margin-left: 30%;
}

.fa-github:hover {
    color: #249cce;
    transition: 0.35s;
}

.fa-envelope {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: #404040;
    font-size: 2.375em;
    transition: 0.35s;
    margin-top: 40%;
    margin-left: 30%;
}

.fa-envelope:hover { 
    color: #249cce;
    transition: 0.35s;
}

.icons:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
  transition: 0.35s;
}

.icons>i>.fa:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

i:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.fa:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="icons">
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1 col-md-offset-3">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-vk fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Блок кода

```
.icons:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
  transition: 0.35s;
}
```

Добавляет полупрозрачность всему блоку, а не иконкам

Его нужно переписать так

```
.icons:hover .fa {
  opacity: 0.4;
  transition: 0.35s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте следующий код:

```
.fa {
 opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Это установка начального `opacity` для иконок.

Comment: мне нужно чтобы при наведении на этот div они становились полупрозрачными, и при наведении на одну из иконок она становилась непрозрачной

Comment: @user234223 тогда просто добавьте вышестоящий код.